# SQL Server Insert with variable column names, variable column values and an unknown number of columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm in the process of making a project where I need to display multiple tables, each on a db grid and have CRUD for all of them, the problem being it's many tables, so I'm dynamically generating a different UI for all tables and writing one size fits all CRUD stored procedures for them.

Everything is working at this point except insert because it's different tables which means variable table names, column names, column values and number of columns, each table also allows nulls and doesn't allow nulls for columns in different positions.

What I did for update was to use dynamic SQL and use a variable table name, col name, col value, col id name and col id value, then loop that for the number of columns the given table has, this approach will however not work with insert, I tried inserting just the primary keys with default values for the rest of the fields where I'll then update the default values right after the insert but it won't work because the number of columns is also variable along with the fact the one column could allow nulls and another in a different table and position doesn't.

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm sure there has to be a way to do this but after searching online for hours I couldn't find anything, thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @str = N'UPDATE DBName..' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET ' +quotename(@colName)+ ' = ''' +@colValue+ ''' WHERE ' +quotename(@colID)+ ' = ' +CAST(@colIDValue AS NVARCHAR(255))+ '';

EXEC (@str)
```

```
rgv = (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView)tConParamTables.SelectedTab.Controls[3];

currentTableName = tConParamTables.SelectedTab.Name;
string colName = "", colValue = "", colID = "";
int colIDValue = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfCols; i++)
{
    txtBoxUpdate = updateTxtBoxList[i];
    colName = commaSepCols[i];
    colValue = txtBoxUpdate.Text;
    colID = commaSepCols[0];
    colIDValue = Convert.ToInt16(rgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
    SetParamTables(_DBCONN, colName, colValue, currentTableName, colID, colIDValue, ref paramsTableSet);
}

selectRow();
updateForm.Dispose();
```

Edit:
I've searched for and tried many different things to solve this and came to one possible solution that could work if it's possible to do.

First:
I use this to get the columns and corresponding data types of a given table, the given table being a param passed to it but for simplicity I used 'TableName' here.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName';
```

So I now have the column names meaning I also know how many columns there are in the table too, but I don't know how to use this in the insert statement.

My current Insert looks like this:

```
SET @str = N'INSERT INTO DBName..' + quotename(@tableName) + 
            '(' + quotename(@colName) + ')' + 
            'VALUES' + '(' + CAST(@colValue AS NVARCHAR(255)) + ')'
```

This could maybe work if not for the fact that if I loop this for the amount of columns there is it will do a new insert on a new row every time.

Comment: "I'm in the process of making a project where I need to display multiple tables, each on a db grid and have CRUD for all of them" - that in itself tends to raise a red flag.....

Comment: Do you mean that it's a bad idea to work with many tables at once ?

Comment: I mean it's generally a bad idea. Letting end users edit  'raw' data is a poor design choice for several reasons.

Comment: This is more for personal use and learning, if end users were to work with it I 100% agree, the goal is to see if instead of doing everything manually for many tables it is possible for a solution where all I have to do is add a new table to the project and everything will fall into place.

Comment: Have you looked into 'Django'?

Comment: I have not, but as far as I know Django is used for web applications ? in which case it will not be ideal to use because i'm trying to do this using c# and winforms, so not through a web based application, if there is however no way to use Insert like this then I will have to reconsider my approach.

Comment: a locally hosted web app. and a desktop app. talking to a sql server are not that different.

Comment: I will have a look at Django then and update progress, thanks alot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, a bit messy so will be looking into better methods in the meantime such as instead of generating the strings in c# to generate them with a while loop in the stored procedure, my current solution is to build a string of column names and values and pass them to my stored procedure as parameters.

C# :

```
        currentTableName = tConParamTables.SelectedTab.Name;
        string colName = "", colValue = "", colValueList = "", colNameList = "";

        txtBoxCreate = insertTxtBoxList[0];
        colNameList = commaSepCols[0];
        colValueList = txtBoxCreate.Text;

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfCols; i++)
        {
            txtBoxCreate = insertTxtBoxList[i];
            colName = commaSepCols[i];
            colValue = txtBoxCreate.Text;
            colNameList = colNameList + "," + colName;
            colValueList = colValueList + "'" + "," + "'" + colValue;
        }

        InsertParamTables(_DBCONN, currentTableName, colNameList, colValueList);
        selectLastRow();
        createForm.Dispose();
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @str = N'INSERT INTO DBName..' + quotename(@tableName) + '(' + @colNameList + ')' + 'VALUES' + '(''' + @colValueList + ''')';

EXEC (@str)
```